# ASP.NET MVC - Can I create an invisible Ajax.ActionLink()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

**Is it possible to create an invisible Ajax.ActionLink?**

```
Ajax.ActionLink("", "Action", Args, AjaxArgs)
```

The above doesn't work, LinkName (1st argument) cannot be Null or Empty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a style html attribute:

```
Ajax.ActionLink("LinkText", "Action", Args, AjaxArgs,new{style="display:none;"})
```

Comment: Nice, overlooked the last optional argument :)

Answer (score 1):

You might just have to wrap it in a div like this:

```
<div style="{display:none}">Ajax.ActionLink("", "Action", Args, AjaxArgs)</div>
```